# AWS CloudWatch Alarm triggering wrongly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am looking forward to understand how the alarms are triggered.

**The case is a follows:**

Currently, I have set up a custom metric for a `Log Group`. These are the logs of an R script running with AWS ECS, and the custom metric is set to `1` whenever it finds the keyword `done` in the logs, otherwise, it will set to `0`.

**The alarm was setup to check 1 data point, and whenever it finds 0 it will be triggered.**

**Now the issue** is that I have been receiving the alarm randomly without reason, as the logs indicate the script has been running successfully (All of them contain the keyword `done`). Then after a while, and before the time period setup happens again, the status changes back to `OK`.

```
{
    "MetricAlarms": [
        {
            "AlarmName": "XXXXXXXXX",
            "AlarmArn": "XXXXXXXXX",
            "AlarmConfigurationUpdatedTimestamp": "2020-07-27T07:08:34.498000+00:00",
            "ActionsEnabled": true,
            "OKActions": [],
            "AlarmActions": [
                "XXXXXXXXX:slack-monitoring"
            ],
            "InsufficientDataActions": [],
            "StateValue": "OK",
            "StateReason": "Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [1.0 (26/07/20 07:10:00)] was not less than or equal to the threshold (0.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for ALARM -> OK transition).",
            "StateReasonData": "{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"queryDate\":\"2020-07-27T07:10:51.284+0000\",\"startDate\":\"2020-07-26T07:10:00.000+0000\",\"statistic\":\"Maximum\",\"period\":86400,\"recentDatapoints\":[1.0],\"threshold\":0.0}",
            "StateUpdatedTimestamp": "2020-07-27T07:10:51.285000+00:00",
            "MetricName": "XXXXXXXXX",
            "Namespace": "XXXXXXXXX",
            "Statistic": "Maximum",
            "Dimensions": [],
            "Period": 86400,
            "EvaluationPeriods": 1,
            "DatapointsToAlarm": 1,
            "Threshold": 0.0,
            "ComparisonOperator": "LessThanOrEqualToThreshold",
            "TreatMissingData": "missing"
        }
    ],
    "CompositeAlarms": []
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of the alarm configuration :)

Comment: @ChrisWilliams added the alarm configuration.

Comment: So if I get this right, if there are 0 datapoints in a 24 hour period (which is evaluated once per day) this alarm should trigger?

Comment: Correct :) @ChrisWilliams

The task being monitored is scheduled daily, and it is running succesfully all days.